# How to model cache hits

Tags: probability, distributions

I'd like to model the behavior of a server A, which caches results from an upstream server B. Queries sent to server A will be forwarded to server B if the former has not already seen this query for an entry.

Relaxations and parameters:

- There are `x` total entries in server B, which can be cached in server A
- A query for an entry is chosen uniformly from the set of `x` entries
- We will query `y` entries to server A
- Server A has an empty cache initially
- Server A has enough space to cache at least `x` entries
- no further cache invalidation

Now what I'd like to be able to calculate is, after `y` queries how many of those queries are expected to be cached at server A.
I'm having trouble decomposing the problem in, what seems like  elementary statistics problems.